# Load Database Values to Google Map

Tags: javascript, mysql, codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I want to do something similar to [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bmSbU/154/)
but I want to load the latitude and longitude values from the database.I was able to load the marker on the map but it does not move.I am using Codeigniter framework and Google Map JS API v3. I am using Mysql as the database. Here are codes:

```
//inside the setInterval function of the above demo
interval = window.setInterval(function() { 
  <?php
    $this->load->model('Maps/Maps_Model'); 
    $data['result11'] = $this->Maps_Model->getLastPagination();
  ?>

  var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $result11->lat; ?>,<?php echo   $result11->lon; ?>);
  marker.setPosition(pos);

}, 10);

//inside my model
function getLastPagination(){    

  $query = $this->db->query("select lat,lon from map order by id DESC limit 1");
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
    $row = $query->row();
    return $row;
  }

}
```

Comment: What do you expect ? You don't update or change the marker position. Your marker can't move...

Comment: There is no error in your code, the marker is not moving because you didn't change its position by the time. Please read your demo code to understand what I mean.

Comment: I thought  when I run the setInterval function, the code run like a loop for 10 miliseconds and there by getLastPagination() function calls itself so that I can always get the latest latitude and longitude. I am new-bee to PHP and JS both. Sorry if I am mistaken.